# Google Spreadsheet formula for something like "=B(SpecificCellValue)"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking for a formula which I can use to batch copy paste into my chart. The tricky part is that I'm importing specific lines from another Tab. So lemme draw you a picture of what I need:

```
TAB1 has:
   A     B
1 Name   Age
2 Joe    34
3 Susan  27
4 Paul   19
5 Nick   22

TAB2 has:
   A   B
1  ID  Age
2  2   =TAB1!B(A2) or even =TAB1!B(A(row()))
3  4   =TAB1!B(A3) or even =TAB1!B(A(row()))
4  5   =TAB1!B(A4) or even =TAB1!B(A(row()))
```

All I know is that =row() returns me the current line of the cell I'm running this formula, but I have no clue on how to "concatenate" A+row() to acquire the TAB1!B(ID) that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=INDIRECT("TAB1!B"&ROW())`

If you are looking for an exact import of Tab1 and nothing else try this in A1 of Tab2 `=query('TAB1'!A:B,"Select A,B")`...it will automatically add additional data as soon as it is entered in tab1.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done many custom functions. But I think this works.

```
function ageFinder(idcell)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('TAB1');
  var sht2=ss.getSheetByName('TAB2');
  var row=sht2.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var id=sht2.getRange('A' + row).getValue();
  var r=sht1.getRange('B' + id).getValue();
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I forgot to mention I can't use Scripts/functions. This Spreadsheet is at the very edge of daily server computer usage :(

But there must be a way to assemble that, still :c

Thank your for this effort tho!

Comment: If your that close to the edge, then perhaps this would be a time to begin replacing some of the inline functions with scripts that process the entire sheet in array format which is much faster.

Comment: true, and I'm working on that, but I'm acquiring data from another websites and I still need to update my charts with a higher rate =/